# ; or ) expected error in Android studio while calling a function in main class from DBHelper class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to call a function updatebudget from my DBHelper class,if the condition is true,I am getting the error :- or ) expected in the line- after Integer,String in every parameters..

Main Class-

```
> mydb.updateBudget(Integer idd,Integer phon, String bdat, String acc,
> String det,  String with,  String dep, String acc, String breco);


Main Class-


>  public void subjour(View V)
>     {
> 
>         String with=bwithdraw.getText().toString();
>         String dep=bdeposit.getText().toString();
>         String acc=baccountname.getText().toString();
>         String bdat=bdate.getText().toString();
>         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
>         String det=bdetails.getText().toString();
>         String breco=brec.getText().toString();
>         String phon=phone.getText().toString();
>         int idd=0;
> 
> 
>         if( (with.equals(""))&&(dep.equals(""))) {
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the deposit or withdrawl amount",
>                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>         else if (!validateFirstName(acc)) {
> 
>             baccountname.setError("Please enter  valid  name");
>         }
> 
> 
> 
> 
>         else if(mydb.insertBudget(bdate.getText().toString(), >bdetails.getText().toString(),
>                 >bwithdraw.getText().toString(),bdeposit.getText().toString(),baccountname.getTe>xt().toString(),brec.getText().toString()
>         )){
>            mydb.updateBudget(Integer idd,Integer phon, String bdat, String acc, String det,  String with,  String dep, String acc, String
> breco);
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "journal created",
>                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         } else{
>             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not created",
>                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
> 
>     }
>     }
```

DBHelper class-

```
> public boolean updateBudget(int idd,int phone, String bdate, String
> baccountname, String bdetails, Integer bwithdrawl, Integer bdeposit,
> String baccount, String brec) {
>         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
>         ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
>         contentValues.put("bdate", bdate);
>         contentValues.put("bdetails", bdetails);
>         contentValues.put("bwithdrawl", bwithdrawl);
>         contentValues.put("bdeposit", bdeposit);
>         contentValues.put("baccountname",baccountname);
>         contentValues.put("brec", brec);
>         String selectQuery = "select id, phone from  " +  CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME;
>         //Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from budget where idd=" + idd + "", null);
>         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
> 
>         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>             phone=  Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1));
> 
>         }
> 
>             phone +=bdeposit;
>             phone =phone - bwithdrawl;
> 
>         cursor.close();
>         db.close();
> 
> 
>         //Your Update to SQLite
>         db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
>         values.put(String.valueOf(phone), phone);
>         db.update("budget", contentValues, "idd = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(idd)});
>         db.update(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE , values, idd + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(phone) });
>         db.close();
>         return true;
>     }
```

Please let me know where I am wrong-
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

When you call a method (as opposed to declaring one), you need to omit the argument types. So instead of:

```
mydb.updateBudget(Integer idd,Integer phon, ...
```

you need:

```
mydb.updateBudget(idd, phon, ...
```

Of course, there may be other errors in your code; I'm only addressing the one related to the error message you posted.

Comment: Thanks ..a lot..that worked